# create new element from array until array is empty every second

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

Trying to create an element using items from an array that are randomly selected every other second until array is empty. I am stumped why my function works when i don't append the element to the dom but as soon as i add to the dom the array just gets larger and ends up crashing the dom.

My plan is to eventually create a new object that has the image, css with random xy position and then append a new element to the dom using the object values.

Basically i am trying to add random images to the dom every second and have them animate in and out until the array is empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
    "load": function(){
        var imgArray = ['brain', 'mitochondria', 'microscope', 'beaker', 'beaker-2', 'scientist', 'cell', 'atom', 'dropper'];

        window.setInterval(function(){
            var imgItem;
            if( imgArray.length >= 1 ) {
                var index = Math.floor( Math.random()*imgArray.length );
                console.log( imgArray[index] ); // Log the item
                imgItem = ( imgArray[index] ); // Log the item

                imgArray.splice( index, 1 ); // Remove the item from the array
                // $('form').append('<img class="img-animation" src="img/science/'+ imgItem +'.svg" alt="'+ imgItem +'">');
            }
        }, 1000);

    },
```

This is the console when i don't append new image:

```
home.js:11 beaker
home.js:11 dropper
home.js:11 microscope
home.js:11 beaker-2
home.js:11 atom
home.js:11 brain
home.js:11 scientist
home.js:11 cell
home.js:11 mitochondria
```

If i add the new image to the dom it will eventually crash and the loop goes on forever which makes no sense to me.

Comment: Have you considered logging the contents of the array on each iteration, then it might *show* you why/where it's going wrong. To prevent the infinite loop use a another variable in the `if`, for example: `if (imgArray.length && iterationLimit)` (after initialising `iterationLimit = 10`, for example), which will allow only 10 iterations; in both cases `0` is falsey, so once either of the numbers reach `0` the `if` will condition will be `false` and so stop).

Comment: I'm also curious to see if this "load" callback gets re-invoked after updating the DOM.

Comment: I am using Meteor as my framework

Comment: I am not following you with how you said to implement the iterationLimit. I am assuming that i should decrease the limit by one every iteration in loop? It looks the the loop adds to the imgItem variable because the images starts appearing in pairs as if it is doubling each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are setting an interval, it will keep calling itself to check the if every second long after the array is empty, even if thats not the issue I recommend you to do something like this:

```
var imgArray = ['brain', 'mitochondria', 'microscope', 'beaker', 'beaker-2', 'scientist', 'cell', 'atom', 'dropper'];

var getAllRandomly = function(arr) {
    if (arr.length) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        console.log(arr[index]); // Log the item
        imgItem = (arr[index]); // Log the item
        imgArray.splice(index, 1); // Remove the item from the array
        setTimeout(function() {
            getAllRandomly(arr);
        }, 1000);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Array is empty');
    }
};

getAllRandomly(imgArray);
```

This way, the function will call itself and return one result every second until the array is empty.

Now going to the real problem:
Your 'load' function is probably being called multiple times, setting a lot of intervals with the same array. If the loop is really infinite then it might be calling itself somehow.
Try leaving just a console log on your load function and run your script to see if the log appears multiple times.

Comment: That's exactly what i was trying to accomplish, thank you so much!